# Cassandra remove local peer

Tags: configuration, cassandra

I have mysterious bug in three-node cassandra cluster. Every time i'm connecting to my cluster i'm getting

> 15/06/02 14:41:24 ERROR Session: Error creating pool to
>   /127.0.0.1:9042 com.datastax.driver.core.TransportException:
>   [/127.0.0.1:9042] Cannot connect

Sometimes it's only slows down startup, but sometimes it's crytical, for example every but first job with [cassandra-connector](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector)'s `CassandraTableScanRDD` yield

> java.io.IOException: Failed to open thrift connection to Cassandra at
>   127.0.0.1:9160

I verified that single node causing this, i.e. all work fine when it's down. At this node i found strange record in peers. When i running

```
cql> select peer, rpc_address from peers ;
```

at this node, i'm getting

```
 peer          | rpc_address
---------------+---------------
    10.99.0.12 |     127.0.0.1
    {node 1}   |     {node 1}
    {node 3}   |     {node 3}
```

While any other node yields only other peers and no localhost `rpc_address`.

When i'm trying to  run 
`nodetool removenode {this node id}` i'm getting

> java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Cannot remove self

How could i fix this peer error?

Answer (score 0):

Thing i have basically done - is deleting `system/peers-...` directory under the 
`/var/lib/cassandra/data` and restarted the service.

It have fixed the error but i think this is little bit brute. So i'd like to see another option.